# Read uploaded Excel file

Tags: php, excel

I am working in PHP. I have moved the uploaded Excel file to a folder on my local server my code is

```
if(isset($_POST["btnImport"]))
                 {
                      $uploads_dir = 'C:/wamp/www/quiz admin/uploads';
                      $tmp_name = $_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"];
                      $name = $_FILES["excelFile"]["name"];
                    if(!empty($_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"]))
                     {
                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
                        $fileupload = $_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"];                          
                        $fileName = explode(".",$_FILES["excelFile"]["name"]);
                        if($fileName[1]=="xls"||$fileName[1]=="xlsx")
                        {
                        $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($name);
```

The files which I uploaded are moved to "uploads" folder but when I am trying to read these file by using:

```
                    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($name);
```

It returns:

> "The filename sample xls.xls is not readable"

what to do ? How to read the uploaded files from the uploads folder ??

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to be referencing the $name variable which stores just the name itself but you've moved the file to $uploads_dir/$name.
Try

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($uploads_dir.'/'.$name);
```

Comment: if .xls is working but not .xlsx I would imagine your probably using PEAR rather than the PHPExcel Library. You will need [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read the .xlsx files